# Find the value of the given integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Find the value of the integral - $$\int \cfrac{\cos^3 x + \cos^5 x}{\sin^2 x + \sin^4 x}dx $$

**EDIT : This is what I've tried**

> $$\int\cfrac{\cos x (\cos^2 x + \cos^4 x)}{\sin^2 x + \sin^4 x} dx \\
> \int \cfrac{((1-t^2) + (1-t^2)^2)}{t^2 + t^4} dt \\
> \text{Where t = sin x } \\
> \int \cfrac{t^4 - 3t^2 + 2}{t^2 + t^4} \\
> \int \cfrac{t^2 + t^4 - 4t^2 + 2}{t^2 + t^4} \\
> \int \left(1 - \cfrac{(4t^2 - 2)}{t^2 + t^4}\right) dt$$
>   After solving this, I got - 
>   $\sin x + 2\csc x - 2\tan^{-1} (\sin x) $ .
>   While the answer is, $\sin x + 2\csc x - 6\tan^{-1}(\sin x) $

Comment: A user of 700 reputation should know that when posting a question, the question gets closed if no own work is shown. What did you try so far? How far did you get?

Comment: A question formulated like this is more likely to receive an answer at [Wolfram](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=%28Cos%5Bx%5D%5E3%2BCos%5Bx%5D%5E5%29%2F%28Sin%5Bx%5D%5E2+%2B+Sin%5Bx%5D%5E4%29&random=false).

Comment: What is *the value* of an *indefinite* integral?

Comment: I apologize for not providing details for what I've tried. I was on mobile and really needed help for next day's test, and am not acquainted to type LaTeX on mobile, it just takes a lot of time. No excuses, I've provided details now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\cos^3 x + \cos^5 x}{\sin^2 x + \sin^4 x} = \frac{\cos^3 x(1 + \cos^2 x)}{\sin^2 x(1+ \sin^2 x)}=\cos x\dfrac{(1-\sin^2x)(2-\sin^2x)}{\sin^2 x(1+ \sin^2 x)}$$

Setting $\sin x=u$ we get

$$\int\dfrac{(1-u^2)(2-u^2)}{u^2(1+u^2)}du$$

Using [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html), $\dfrac{(1-u^2)(2-u^2)}{u^2(1+u^2)}=\dfrac Au+\dfrac B{u^2}+\dfrac{C+Du}{1+u^2}+E$ where $A,B,C,D,E$ are arbitrary constants

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't quite find the answer myself. I got this far:
$$\int \frac{\cos^3 x + \cos^5 x}{\sin^2 x + \sin^4 x} dx = \int \frac{\cos^3 x(1 + \cos^2 x)}{\sin^2 x(1+ \sin^2 x)} dx$$
Putting this into Wolfram-Alpha gave this [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20cos%5E3%28x%29%281%2Bcos%5E2%28x%29%29%2F%28sin%5E2%28x%29%281%2Bsin%5E2%28x%29%29%29).
$$\sin(x) - \tan(\frac{x}{2}) - \cot(\frac{x}{2}) - 6 \tan^{-1}(\sin(x)) + c$$ Where c is a constant.